# PHPMailer can't instantiate mail function?

Tags: php, iis, phpmailer

I have a site running on IIS8 and I got PHPMailer working just fine. Then out of nowhere I start getting this error "Message was not sent.Mailer error: Could not instantiate mail function." It also looks like another php email form that doesn't use PHPMailer isn't working either. By not working I mean it appears to work but the email never shows up in my inbox. I have no idea if this is an IIS or PHP issue. Here is the PHPMailer form.

```
<?php

require_once('assets/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$job = $_POST['job'];
$file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['name'];


$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From = "jobform@url.com";
$mail->FromName  =  "Job Form";
$address = "email@url.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;  

$mail->Subject = " Job Form";
$mail->Body="
            First Name: $first_name
            Last Name: $last_name
            Phone Number: $phone
            Email: $email
            Job: $job";

$maxsize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
$types = array('application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');


if ((isset($_FILES['fileUpload']) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) && $_FILES['fileUpload']['size'] < $maxsize && in_array( $_FILES['fileUpload']['type'], $types)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'],
                         $_FILES['fileUpload']['name']);
} else {

  echo 'Please upload a PDF or Word Document that is under 2MB';
  exit();

}

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {

      echo 'Please enter a valid email address';
      exit();
}

if($first_name == '') {
      echo 'Please enter your first name';
      exit();
}

if($last_name == '') {
      echo 'Please enter your last name';
      exit();
}


if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo 'Thank you for your feedback.';
}

?>
```

Comment: It sounds like a server issue. Is it your own server? Can you check whether anything has been upgraded recently on the server, or any relevant permissions or config changed.

Comment: As far as I know, nothing was changed or upgraded. I restarted the server and the smtp server but that didn't help.